# Inserting an item into list UI with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm just learning Meteor and wondered if anyone could help me with this issue.
I'm building a gumtree style listing website to get a bit of practice.

There's a Listings collection which gets displayed onto screen, that shows all of the most recent listings that users have created. (sample code below)

What I want to know is, how can I randomly insert a banner into the list of items (think sponsored item style). I want a chunk of HTML to be inserted into the page at random point in the list every time the page loads.

I tried to put the results Listings.find() into an array and then push in the advert in results_list.js but that didn't work. After doing a bit of reading I get that it's because you're only returning a cursor, so I'm not quite sure how to go about this. I'm coming from a purely angular background here.

My guess is some sort of helper function but I'm not sure where to start so any pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated.

---

*results_list.html*

```
<template name="resultsList">
    {{#each results}}
        {{> resultDetails}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

*results_list.js*

```
Template.resultsList.helpers({
  results: function() {
    return Listings.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}});
  }
});
```

---

UPDATE!

Apologies guys, I read through some more docs and I think I've worked it out, would still like to get your feedback on this solution though as there may be a better way of doing this.

This should add an advert in at a random point (excluding the start and the end). I'll modify the resultDetails template to have an option for advertisement being true that will display the advert code as well.

```
Template.resultsList.helpers({
  results: function() {
    var searchResults = Listings.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}}).fetch();
    searchResults.splice(_.random(1, results.length - 1), 0, {advertisement: true});
    return searchResults;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to modify your `resultDetails` template.

```
<template name='resultDetails'>
  {{#if showBanner}}
    {{> banner}}
  {{/if}}
  ..resultDetails html..
</template>
```

Your helper function can return `showBanner` according to random:

```
Template.resultDetails.helpers({
  showBanner: function(){
    return Math.random()>0.98; // show the banner with probability 0.02
  }
});
```

This will get a bit more complicated if you have rules like *the banner must appear exactly once*. In that case you'll need to do the logic based on the full cursor (for example in the `onRendered` handler for `resultsList`) and pre-compute the position in the list where you want to show the banner.